# Validate a form depending on which submit button is used

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

So, I have this code

```
<script>
    function validate(f) {
        var ok = true;
        if (f.id.value === '' || f.id.value === null) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    function validate2(f) {
        var ok = true;
        if (f.name.value === '' || f.name.value === null) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }
</script>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send_id" value="Send ID"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send_name" value="Send Name"/>
</form>
```

How can I do it to validate the form depending on which submit is used? 
I want to execute validate(); if the Send Id button is clicked and validate2() if we use the other one.

Comment: what is parameter `f` in you validate functions?

Comment: Why cannot you just make two different forms?

Comment: parameter f is the form itself, and i cannot make two differents forms because I cannot nest them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send_id" value="Send ID" onclick="return validate();" />
    <input type="submit" name="send_name" value="Send Name" onclick="return validate2();" />
</form>
```

This way when your functions return `false` (meaning the form is not valid) the submit is interrupted.

And get your `f` parameter manually.

```
function getForm() {
    return document.getElementById("myForm");
}
function validate() {
    var f = getForm();
    var ok = true;
    if (f.id.value === '' || f.id.value === null) {
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
}

function validate2() {
    var f = getForm();
    var ok = true;
    if (f.name.value === '' || f.name.value === null) {
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

You have to give an id to your form as show above.

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than I thought

Answer (score 0):

Have another function as `checkValidate()` or something as you like and check it on click of both the `buttons`

```
<script>
    function checkValidate(buttonName) {
        if(buttonName == 'send_id'){
           return validate();
        }else{
            return validate2();
        }
    }

    function validate() {
        var ok = true;
        if (f.id.value === '' || f.id.value === null) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    function validate2() {
        var ok = true;
        if (f.name.value === '' || f.name.value === null) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }
</script>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send_id" value="Send ID" onclick="return checkValidate(this.name)"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send_name" value="Send Name" onclick="return checkValidate(this.name)"/>
</form>
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks that's what I've been looking for

Comment: Did you test it? I could guess that if your don't return the value returned by `checkValidate` the submit will happen even if the form is not valid. Check my answer below.

Comment: `onclick="return checkValidate(this.name)"` rather than `onclick="checkValidate(this.name)"`

Comment: No, I heven't tested it, I used your answer

Answer (score -2):

Not tested.. but something like that...

```
$( "input[name='send_id']" ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  validate();
  $("form").submit();
});
$( "input[name='send_name']" ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  validate2();
  $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: the OP does not use jQuery